# Phrases or expressions indicating movement to someone's location?

Tags: phrase-request

I'm looking for phrases that can used in spoken English in the following context:

You are talking with someone over the phone and want to inform them that ***you are going***/***will be going*** to their location and they can expect to see you shortly. Also, does it make any difference if the distance is short or long? If it does, I'm looking for a phrase that can be used for short distances, meaning that, say, you and the other person are **NOT** in 2 different cities.

Comment: "I'm on my way. See you soon!"  Or, "I'm on my way to see you. I'll be there in a few minutes." Or, "I'll see you in a few minutes, I'm almost there."

Comment: @Willow Thanks. Can you also say: "I'm coming over there." assuming that the other person is not at his house. Is there a chance that this may imply going to their home for a visit? (which is not the intended meaning)

Comment: of course, that's fine. There are many ways to say it. If the person knows you know where they are it is not complicated. With cell phones you might need to ask if they are at home first!

Comment: So it won't be confused with "come over" meaning coming to someone's home for a friendly visit?

Comment: If I am at home and you call and ask or say you are coming over, or (this would be less likely) coming over *there*, I know exactly what you mean. If I am expecting you to meet me at the museum, I would also understand perfectly.  If you say, "I'm coming over there", it could also be a threat, but only your tone of voice would tell me that and our knowledge of each other.

Answer (score 2):

References:

http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-go.html

http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-be.html

http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-arrive.html

http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-english-verb-leave.html

There are several options, it depends what verb you wish to use.  You mention "will be going" (future continuous) which implies that you will be leaving your current location shortly, however, to imply to someone that you will see them soon, you might wish to use the word "arrive".  Also, the verb **to go** is often used to leave for somewhere unspecific, if you are referring to two specific locations, you usually use the verb **to leave**, eg "I will be leaving (my house) soon"

Examples include:

- I will be arriving *shortly* - future continuous tense of arrive and use of the adverb shortly to describe the rapidness of the verb arrive
- I will be there *soon* - future tense of be and use of "there" as a pronoun
- I will be leaving *soon* - future continuous of leave
- I will be right there - use of "right" as an adjective and "there" as a pronoun
- I won't be long
- I will arrive soon
- I'm just leaving
- I'll be there in a minute/second
- I'm not far away
- We're not far apart
- You're not far from my location
- I'm not far away
- We're a short distance away and it won't take me long to find you

There is no distinction between short time and short distance.  If you say "I'll be there soon" you could either mean that you are traveling fast or that the distance is short, there is no easy way to differentiate in English.

Answer (score 1):

From you comments it seems that you are familiar with the phrasal verb *come over*.

According to the [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/come-over) it has two similar meanings that fit your intent:: "to visit someone in the place where they are, especially their house" and "to travel to a place, especially a long way across water in order to live in a new country".

The first use can be intransitive, which means you don't have to specify the destination - it is where the other person is at the monent.

If you do specify a destination, it may implicitly tell how far away you are. "I'm coming over to your house" means I'm likely in the same city, "to Los Angeles" means I'm out of L.A. but maybe not too far, "to California" would mean I'm out of state, "to the US" means... you understand thd idea.